# How to yield from a Ruby block?

Tags: ruby, block, yield

I have a function that takes a block. This block also takes a block:

```
def fn
  yield do n
    puts n
  end
end

fn do
  yield 1
end
```

This code should print "1". What it actually does, however, is fail:

> syntax error, unexpected keyword_do

I can make the function take a proc instead:

```
def fn(&block)
  block.() do n
    puts n
  end
end
```

However in this case, the code fails on the yield line with:

> no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError)

I don't want to make the inner block a proc:

```
fn do |&block|
  block.(1)
end
```

Because it looks awful. I'd prefer to yield instead, at least in the inner block. How can I solve this?

Comment: Lambdas and procs don't look terrible. That reputation is not deserved.

Comment: I wouldn't call it polluting. And it's not your question. You gave up all rights by publishing on this site, where it automatically becomes creative commons. You can't claim ownership.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your usage of procs is that you use the ugly syntax. That's why they look awful. Usage of `.call` is much more common:

```
def fn(&block)
  block.call do |n|
    puts n
  end
end

fn do |&block|
  block.call(1)
end
```

As to why your two attempts failed, in order:

1. `yield` is a keyword, not a method call. That's why you failed to pass it a block.
2. `yield` yields to the current block. But there is no block in that context: `fn` invocation is not in a method call to which a block is passed. It being executed as a top-level expression.

To summarize: use procs. Abandon hopes of doing this with `yield`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot yield from a block alone. The `yield` keyword always acts in the scope of a method. See the [documentation for method definitions](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument) or the [documentation for Ruby keywords](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/keywords_rdoc.html):

> **yield**
>
> Starts execution of the block sent to the current method.